# Reg Exp For javascript

Tags: regex

hiii every body

i need help for this reg expression pattern

i need to search on text for this

```
( anything ) -
```

check this example to every statement

i need to detect if this pattern exist on the statement that i will feed to my function and get the matched string

be careful for space and braces and dash and  anything  mean any content Arabic or English no matter what is it , just pattern start with ( and end to - and if this pattern exist on the first statement so it say exist

thanks for every one .....

Comment: give some example and expected output ! and what have you tried ?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

The task can be easier if it is described in a way "guiding to"
the proper solution. Let's rewrite your task the following way:

The text to match:

- Should start with `(` and a space.
- Then there is a non-empty sequence of chars other than `)`
  (the text between parentheses, which you wrote as *anything*).
- The last part is a space, `)`, another space and `-`.

Having such a description, it is obvious, that the pattern should be:

```
\( [^)]+ \) -
```

where each fragment: `\(`, `[^)]+` and `\) -` expresses each of the
above conditions.

Note: If spaces after `(` and before `)` are optional, then you can express it
with `?` after each such space, and then the whole regex will change to
`\( ?[^)]+ ?\) -`.